# Linear behavior from 0-10V and steady at 3.3V from 10-24V

Tags: circuit-design, linear-regulator

[image: Voltage cutoff]

Apologies as I have very basic electronics background, and after searching for a whole afternoon I couldn't find out how to implement a circuitry that has this behavior as shown in the graph.

If anyone can point me in a general direction or any available existing reference this would be very much appreciated! E.g. Is there a name for this kind of circuitry, common components used, like transistors or diodes etc. Thanks much!!

Comment: What should that be for, a power supply? Signal filter?

Comment: For a low current, high input resistance application a resistive voltage divider with a zener in parallel to the lower leg would work.

Comment: This is to tap out voltage signals (from sensors, which usually ouput 0-10V but i need it to work for 24V output) to be read by my micro-controller which works on 3.3V.

Comment: I would suggest updating your question with detailed information about your application, since it doesn't seem like what you really want is what you asked for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with 3 alternatives that will most likely suffice. As someone who has "very basic electronics background", I don't assume that you've got diodes or operational amplifiers laying around. So that's why I'll propose several circuits.

---

First off is the circuit that will follow your graph and overshoot by 1 mV.

[image: op-amp solution]

There's two 10k in parallel instead of one 5k because if you use three resistors of the same kind then it's very likely that you'll reach 3.33 V if you feed it 10 V. I chose 10 k because it's not too small or too high. As we say in Swedish, it's "lagom".

If you look at the bottom graph in the image above you will see the same graph that you were asking for.

The operational amplifier (op-amp), is used as a comparator and clipper, if your input is below what you put into the minus sign of the op-amp (3.3V) then the op-amp won't do anything, if you go above 3.3 V then it will activate the N-mosfet and pull down your output so it stays at 3.3 V. This answers your question, however you might not have an op-amp or an N-mos or NPN BJT.

---

Secondly comes the circuit that is maybe "good enough" for you.

[image: diodes limiting]

It's not exactly what @inkyvoyd proposed because I used several diodes instead of one zener because not everybody keep a 3.3 V Zener at their house. Diodes ([0.5 - 0.8] V voltage drop) however may lay around, or a blue LED, they usually have around 3.4 V voltage drop.

Again I put two 10 k resistors in parallel for ease of use.

As you can see at the bottom of the image there's a voltage graph, the bottom one shows the output, and it's not as sharp as the first graph in the first image. So that's what you might expect with 10 k ohm resistors, if you would use three 10 ohm resistors then it might be near the same sharpness as the first image, but 10 ohm resistors will burn up when you feed it 24 V. So don't do that.

If you however would replace the diodes with one 3.3 V zener diode then it would behave nearly identical like the op-amp solution.

---

Thirdly, here's the schematic that I want you to use instead.

[image: 24V down to 3.3V]

instead of making a non-linear curve that you want, why not make a linear curve and make up for it in software?

So 0 V input gives 0 V output, 24 V input gives 3.3 V output. This will result in 10 V input giving 1.375 V output. Then you just scale that in software.

It's by far the easiest solution of the three proposed solutions, just two components. However it requires a 1.6 k ohm resistor which is most certainly not something a typical person got laying around.

So perhaps a 10 k potentiometer (or higher, 100 k would be nice) could be used instead, and trim it so it gives 3.3 V if you feed it 24 V and you're set. One component that you most likely have laying around. DO NOT use a 1 k ohm potentiometer.

If you use a 1 k ohm potentiometer then it will burn off \$\frac{24^2}{1000}=0.576W\$. 0.5 W for a sensor is nasty! Also it might heat up to nasty high temperatures.

---

[Here's the schematics in simulation form so you can see for yourself and change values if you want.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2014.235633750745258%2050%205%2050%0Ar%20240%20176%20240%20400%200%2010000%0Aw%20384%20176%20512%20176%202%0Ag%20240%20400%20240%20416%200%0AR%20256%2096%20224%2096%200%204%20100%2012%2012%200%200.5%0Ag%20304%20400%20304%20416%200%0Ar%20304%20176%20304%20400%200%2010000%0Aw%20304%20176%20240%20176%200%0Ad%20384%20176%20384%20208%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20384%20208%20384%20240%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20384%20272%20384%20304%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20384%20240%20384%20272%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20384%20176%20304%20176%200%0Ad%20384%20304%20384%20336%201%200.805904783%0Ag%20384%20400%20384%20416%200%0Aw%20256%2096%20304%2096%202%0Ad%20384%20368%20384%20400%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20384%20336%20384%20368%201%200.805904783%0Ag%20704%20400%20704%20416%200%0Aw%20704%20320%20832%20320%202%0Ar%20704%20320%20704%20400%200%201600%0Ar%20704%20240%20704%20320%200%2010000%0Ar%20304%2096%20304%20176%200%2010000%0Ar%201024%20240%201024%20320%200%2010000%0Aw%20976%20240%201024%20240%202%0Aw%201136%20320%201024%20320%200%0Aw%201024%20320%20960%20320%200%0AR%20976%20240%20944%20240%200%204%20100%2012%2012%200%200.5%0Af%201184%20384%201136%20384%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%201136%20320%201136%20352%200%0Ag%201136%20400%201136%20416%200%0Aw%201232%20304%201232%20384%200%0Aw%201232%20384%201184%20384%200%0Ar%201024%20320%201024%20400%200%2010000%0Ar%20960%20320%20960%20400%200%2010000%0Ag%201024%20400%201024%20416%200%0Ag%20960%20400%20960%20416%200%0Aw%201136%20352%201136%20368%200%0Aw%201136%20352%201296%20352%200%0Aw%201296%20352%201424%20352%202%0AR%201136%20288%201136%20256%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0Aa%201136%20304%201232%20304%200%2015%200%201000000%203.3%202.4839172045777267%0AR%20656%20240%20624%20240%200%204%20100%2012%2012%200%200.5%0Aw%20656%20240%20704%20240%202%0Ax%201093%20219%201328%20222%204%2024%20What%5Csyou%5Csasked%5Csfor%0Ax%20615%20182%20844%20185%204%2024%20What%5CsI%5Csrecommend%0Ax%20216%2041%20516%2044%204%2024%20What%5Cswas%5Csrecommended%0Ao%203%2064%200%2012290%2023.99999999990186%200.0001%200%202%203%203%0Ao%201%2064%200%2012290%203.2669636248607925%200.0001%200%202%201%203%0Ao%2018%2064%200%2012290%203.31034482757267%200.0001%200%202%2018%203%0Ao%2038%2064%200%2012290%203.307889738779514%200.0001%200%202%2038%203%0A)

Comment: Tack så mycket @Harry! The first option is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Hi @Harry, just to check, what is the component below the Op-amp and what is it used for?

Comment: @jlyh Either a mosfet transistor of type N (for an example this one: [AO3402](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3402.pdf)). Or a BJT transistor of type NPN (for an example this one: [2N2222](http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/2N2222A.pdf)) with a 1 kΩ resistor between the NPN's base and the output of the op-amp.

Comment: @jlyh Don't let the small size of the AO3402 scare you, you can solder it onto perfboards without any problem. If you look at the datasheet, the distance between the G pin and the S pin is just enough so it can touch two holes on the perfboard, and if you just move the transistor a little bit to the side you will have the D pin laying on the side of a hole.

Comment: @jlyh I am answering how the circuit is working under that "chapter"/"section" in my answer. I have divided my answer in straight horizontal lines to divide my answer into one chapter per circuit. So just look right below the first image at the top of my answer. Otherwise if that's too abstract for you, then just simply click the link at the bottom (just above my profile picture in the answer) so you can simulate the circuit in the web browser. Sometimes words can only get you so far, and once you see the animation of voltage and current everything just clicks.

Comment: Wow!! That's really wonderful! Great work there @Harry!